# How to align spans next each other with texte inside each one?

Tags: angular

I have this content generated dynamically like this

[image: how it looks now]

But I want it like this  ' Offres et tableaux d'amortissement de tous les crédits en cours (Immobilier) [120000 €] '.

```html
<div _ngcontent-caj-c13="" class="col-md-10 px-1 mb-md-0 mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
  Offres et tableaux d'amortissement de tous les crédits en cours 
  <span _ngcontent-caj-c13="" class="d-inline-block ng-star-inserted">(Immobilier)</span>
  <span _ngcontent-caj-c13="" class="ng-star-inserted"> [120000&nbsp;€]</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `align-items-center` in your div, or change it to something like Top-aligned

Comment: Actually i found out that the only way to do properlly is to concat all those together inside one span.

Comment: That's great! As far as I know you are using flexbox with `d-flex align-items-center`, but the `align-items-center` align all the child element in it to center.